# How to open 'input fields' on xhtml page for new entry in the list of users?

Tags: java, arraylist

Try to add new 'entry' to list, which I retreive from BD, but can't open 'input fields' on the bottom of my list! But nothing happend, when click button 'AddNew' and haven't any visible mistake...

My method:

```
public void addNewUser(){
    myList= getUsers();
    Values newValue = new Values();
    newValue.setEditable(true);
    myList.add(newValue);
}
```

I retreive from database list of users in xhtml page here is my methods:

```
private List<Values> valuesList;
private List<Values> myList;
private Values allValues;

private static List<Values> getUsers() {
    try {
        databaseConnection();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
        boolean found = false;
        while (resultSet.next() == true) {
            allValues = new Values();
            allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
            allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
            allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
            allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
            valuesList.add(allValues);
            found = true;
        }
        resultSet.close();
        prepStatement.close();
        close(connection);
        if (found) {
            return valuesList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in getUsers()-->" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return (null);
}

public List<Values> getInformation() {
    return getUsers();
}
public List<Values> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
```

Here is my xhtml page:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{user.information}" var="x" border="1" id="table">
    <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.id}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Order No"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Product name"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Price"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Quantity"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 <h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{user.addNewUser}" update="table"/>
```

Comment: "h:commandButton" don't have update property. you can update/render using ajax otherwise on clicking commandButton it will submit the form. Your issue is rendering or list is not updating?

Comment: Can't open fields for entering data (<h:inputText>) on my page, method addNewUser() work only on empty list myList, but nothing happened when I  connect myList and getUsers()...

Comment: Apparently looks like rendering problem. "myList" adding "newValue" from backend right? But changes are not reflecting in your datatable?

Comment: Have you visited this page? 
https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-add-row-in-jsf-datatable/

Comment: I visit this link, but I need to add new entries directly to list! It works only with empty or final list, the question is how to make it on list which retreives from DB!

Comment: you have 3 lists in code 
private List<Values> valuesList;
private List<Values> myList;
private Values allValues;

adding values to valuesList and in new method adding value to myList. with table you have attached user.information List . when you will update myList how it will reflect in datatable ?

Comment: private Values allvalues is't list. Values is class with getters and setters.

Comment: First I want to make this fields open when clicking AddNew button, without databases!